# Eclipse Crashes and Files are Currupted - How to recover files

Tags: android, eclipse, crash

I was developing an android app and suddenly Eclipse crashed.
When I restarted Eclipse the layout file on which I was working on was corrupted!

[image]

Is there any way to bring it back?
Does Eclipse save it somewhere?

Why this file is not getting read properly?
Other files are proper.

I had worked several hours designing that file. Don't want to spend 4 hours again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse keeps a local history. Right-click on the file, `Replace with... > Local History`. Of course there is a chance that this doesn't exist anymore or has been corrupted also. This is not meant as a replacement for a backup strategy or a robust file system.

There is no chance for us to know why this file was corrupted or why Eclipse crashed. A peek into the error log may help.